# Homomorphic Hash Function

Tags: hash, homomorphism

does any homomorphic hash function exist that preserves the multiplication property?

I found encryption methods like the RSA algorithm but I need a hashing method with relatively low complexity which preserves the multiplication property.

Comment: What multiplication property? Be specific. Also, how about using multiplication by a constant as a first attempt at a hash function?